# Wordpress Whiteboard Framework Query

Tags: wordpress, whiteboard

I am new to programming and web designing. I need a little help.
Whiteboard framework has in the index.php file a code line:

```
<?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'Alert' ) ) : ?>
<!--Wigitized 'Alert' for the home page -->
<?php endif ?>
```

What is it for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`dynamic_sidebar()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar) is a WordPress function. I believe the code within the `if` statement will run if the sidebar named "Alert" is not found or does not contain widgets.